# NSFectchedResultController in UITableView , issue with .Move when data is changed

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am displaying a list of items stored in core data.
The items are ordered by 'lastActivity' date, *and* that last activity date is displayed:

```
| Item 1     12:33 |
--------------------
| Item 2     08:23 |
```

The items can be modified in 'background', in order to be notified of the changes i am using a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

If Item2 is modified, the lastActivityDate is changed and thus the order change is triggering a NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move event.

Currently in my code i am doing this

```
if(type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move) {
    self.tableView?.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: newIndexPath)
}
```

As a result i have this

```
| Item 2     08:23 |  <-- Still displaying old date
--------------------
| Item 1     12:33 |
```

Expected should be

```
| Item 2     12:44 |  <-- Update date
--------------------
| Item 1     12:33 |
```

So the issue is that the moveRowAtIndexPath is not refreshing the content, and that NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move is the only event i receive (there is no other .Update)

Notice that if instead of the moveRowAtIndexPath, i do the classical delete then insert, it's working fine (even animation looks the same)

```
self.tableView?.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath] , withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
self.tableView?.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath] , withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Is there  an issue with using delete then insert instead of move?
I can see that it is creating/deleting or re-using cells, whereas move doesn't.

If i want to keep with the move, what is the best way to refresh cell while (before or after) doing the move?
If i try to update the cell before, i get a  'Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo' error.

Comment: Do you have `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` in the FRC delegate methods (`willChange...` and `didChange...` respectively)?

Comment: yes, i have.
In fact i am building a list of items changes on every 'didChangeObject' call. And after in the didChange, i iterate all the changes inside a single beginUpdates / endUpdates/